# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Estoy realizando un módulo y una consola en Python para el proyecto de un curso. Debo dejar, lo primero es cargar un archivo, lo cual se hace con una función donde se indica el nombre del archivo, de manera que el usuario cuando ejecute la consola brinde el nombre del archivo, el programa lo abra y ejecute lo demás. Pero obtengo el error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Ya verifiqué que existiera el archivo, que esté en la misma carpeta donde están el módulo y la consola, intenté con la ruta completa del archivo y nada, nada funciona.

Este es el código del módulo para cargar el archivo:

```
def cargar_canciones(nombre_archivo: str)-> list:
    canciones = []
    with open(nombre_archivo,"r") as archivo:
        titulos = archivo.readline().strip().split(",")
        
        for linea in archivo:
            info_cancion = linea.strip().split(",")
            nueva_cancion = {
                titulos[i]: info_cancion[i] for i in range(len(titulos))
            }
            canciones.append(nueva_cancion)
            
    return canciones
```

Y este es el código de la consola:

```
def ejecutar_cargar_canciones() -> list:
    """Solicita al usuario que ingrese el nombre de un archivo CSV con los datos de
    las canciones y las carga.
    Retorno: list
        La lista de canciones con la información del archivo.
    """
    canciones = None
    archivo = input("Por favor ingrese el nombre del archivo CSV con las canciones: ")
    canciones = bb.cargar_canciones(archivo)
    if len(canciones) == 0:
        print("El archivo seleccionado no es válido. No se pudieron cargar las canciones del Ranking")
    else:
        print("Se cargaron", len(canciones), "canciones a partir del archivo.")
    return canciones
```

Comment: que tipo de archivo utiliza esto? csv? parece que tienes problemas con las rutas

Comment: Las rutas relativas se resuelven en base al directorio de trabajo actual, no en base al del script que llama a `open()`. Obviamente el error es muy claro, no existe el archivo con esa ruta, para poder explicar claramente que está pasando sería de gran ayuda que agregaras la estructura de tu proyecto, parece que `cargar_canciones` está en otro módulo, por ejemplo, si el directorio de trabajo  es el del script que contiene `ejecutar_cargar_canciones` y el modulo "bb" y el csv están en otra carpeta la ruta será incorrecta.

Comment: Hola. Sí, cargar_canciones y ejecutar_cargar_canciones están en archivos diferentes, pero están en la misma carpeta y dicha carpeta es el directorio de trabajo que estoy usando, por cierto, estoy usando Spyder.

Comment: Buenas! Podrías agregar una captura de cómo se ven los directorios de tu proyecto? Esto tiene pinta de que podría resolverse fácilmente viendo eso. Te recomiendo agregar dicha captura a tu pregunta para que sea más fácil ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

No he evaluado tu codigo de lectura del archivo pero pienso que debes aprender a utilizar la libreria [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) dado que este no es el problema que haz especificado, solo me centrare en como resolver tu problema de localizar el archivo csv. `[Errno 2] No such file or directory`

```
# Debes estudiar mas acerca de rutas relativas y absolutas
import csv, os

# Para obtener la localizacion de el archivo ejecutandose
directorio = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# Para movernos hasta donde esta el archivo CSV
ruta_csv = '../data.csv'

# Estas funciones concatenan las rutas apropiadamente en cualquier sistema operativo
ruta_archivo = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(directorio, ruta_csv))

# Luego recien lo empiezas a usar en tu funcion
...
with open(ruta_archivo, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    ...
```

Suponiendo que la estructura del folder es asi

```
D:\projecto
└───src
    └───main.py
└───data.csv
```