# load_dotenv('.env.dev') no carga

Tags: python, flask, .env

no entiendo por qué no me carga el load_dotenv('.env.dev'), directamente me carga el archivo '.env'. Ambos archivos están en la raíz del proyecto junto con 'app.py'. Según he estado investigando debería funcionarme.
He probado con dotenv_values y con esto sí que me carga el archivo '.env.dev' pero no es lo que necesito.
A ver si algún alma caritativa ve el error.
Gracias de antemano.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import redis
import random
import string
import os

load_dotenv('.env.dev')

app = Flask(__name__)

r = redis.Redis(host=os.getenv("DB_HOST"), port=os.getenv("DB_PORT"), decode_responses=True)

CORS(app, origins=os.getenv("FRONTEND_URL"), supports_credentials=True)
```

Comment: Eso es lo esperado según la [documentación](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv?tab=readme-ov-file#python-dotenv)...

Comment: Así es y no entiendo... Me estoy volviendo un poco loca... Gracias por molestarte.

Comment: parece que tienes un problema para detectar la ubicacion del archivo. revisa [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/616928/48563) utilizando el modulo os puedes resolver las rutas para llegar a tu archivo `.env`

Comment: Hola Egon, 
```
directorio = os.path.dirname(__file__)

ruta_env = '/.env.dev'

ruta_archivo = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(directorio, ruta_env))

load_dotenv(ruta_archivo)

print(os.getenv("DB_HOST"))
```
Creo que lo he hecho bien, corregirme si me equivoco, pero sigue sin funcionar...
El archivo que quiero cargar está en la raíz.
Gracias por tu ayuda Egon.

Comment: Hola Gádor, creo que debe ser  `ruta_env = '.env.dev'`, no  `ruta_env = '/.env.dev'`,  si no me equivoco (no lo he probado) tal como lo tienes te generara una ruta incorrecta y el `print` debería mostrar `None`.

Comment: A pesar de su nombre, la variable file no siempre coincide con la ubicación del script. Al igual que pasa con el directorio de trabajo (el directorio usado para completar las rutas relativas, que son las que no empiezan por el disco). Esto se ve, en el caso de file, por ejemplo, en los exes de pyinstaller y, en el caso de el directorio de trabajo, al ejecutar usando vscode. Prueba importando el modulo sys, y, donde dice file, coloca sys.argv[0]

Comment: Gracias chicxs, mañana volveré a probar pero cambiando el directorio el print me seguía dando la variable de .env y no se .env.dev.

Comment: Buenas de nuevo, @FjSevilla, probé quitando el slash y nada.

Comment: Y @Dante S., tmb he probado lo que me comentaste y sigue printeándome la clave del archivo .env...
Trastearé un poco más sino haré un archivo config.py y colocaré todas las variables de entorno en un mismo archivo .env...xq ya no sé que más intentar...

Comment: ```
PS C:\Users\Gádor\Desktop\Gádor\Full Stack\url-shortener-redis\url-shortener-backend> pipenv shell 
Loading .env environment variables...
Loading .env environment variables...
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
```
Parece que tiene que ver con Pipenv...

Comment: Ups!!! eso ya tiene mas sentido, porque no hay forma de que load_dotenv cargue el archivo .env si no encuentra .env.dev... pipenv carga archivos .env automáticamente por defecto. Puedes configurar pipenv para que [use distintos .env segun el entorno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54896563/7131499) o puedes desactivar la carga automática del .env (o renombrarlo) y seguir con dotenv.

Comment: Aleluya! Muchas gracias @FJSevilla, justo cuando has comentado estaba leyendo sobre ello. Lo que m ha parecido más cómodo es anular la carga automática en los dos archivos y trabajar con dotenv. 
Hace unos meses que he terminado un bootcamp y se agredece muchísimo la ayuda de gente como vosotros, que compartáis todo lo q sabéis, de verdad muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada, la verdad es que estaba un poco intrigado, hasta el punto de ir a ver el código fuente de dotenv, porque el comportamiento que describías no concordaba con como se supone que funiona load_dotenv. Tu mensaje sobre pipenv lo aclaró todo.... He creado una respuesta para la posteridad, los comentarios son efímeros. Si al final has dado con otra forma de hacerlo puedes publicar una respuesta a tu propia pregunta, Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema parece deberse a dos situaciones:

- `load_dotenv` por defecto no sobrescribe variables de entorno existentes.
- Se está usando pipenv, el cual carga por defecto el archivo `.env`.

Esto hace que `$ pipenv shell` cargue el .env y luego `load_dotenv` no tiene efecto porque esas variables de entorno ya existen.

Quizás la opción más directa es usar el argumento `override` de `load_dotenv` para que sobrescriba las variables aunque existan:

```
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv

env_path = Path(__file__).parent.joinpath("./.env.dev").resolve()
load_dotenv(env_path, override=True)
```

**Nota:** si `load_dotenv` no encuentra el archivo especificado no generara ninguna excepción o aviso ni carga otro archivo. Si se desea comprobar si la carga fue exitosa se puede comprobar su retorno (retorna `True`/ `False`).

Otra opción es cargar el .env adecuado con pipenv directamente:

```
$ PIPENV_DOTENV_LOCATION=/path/to/.env pipenv shell
```

Esta [otra respuesta en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54896106/pipenv-multiple-environments/54896563#54896563) muestra otra forma de hacerlo.

O también puedes forzar a pipenv a que no cargue el .env automáticamente:

```
$ PIPENV_DONT_LOAD_ENV=1 pipenv shell
```

y manejarlo todo con `dotenv`.

Ver [pipenv - Environment and Shell Configuration](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/stable/shell.html#environment-and-shell-configuration) para más información.